# WKWebView not load full page from https://mobile.bet365.com

Tags: wkwebview

After `print(html)` I got clear HTML without data.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController,WKNavigationDelegate{


    let webView = WKWebView()

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
                 didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("loaded")
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.innerHTML.toString()",
                                   completionHandler: { (html: Any?, error: Error?) in
                                    print(html)

        })

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL (string: "https://mobile.bet365.com")
        let request = URLRequest (url:url!)
        webView.frame = CGRect (x:0,y:0,width:300,height:300)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        webView.load(request)
        view.addSubview(webView)

    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work with other URLs?

Comment: When you say "clear HTML without any data" you mean you are succeeding to load the page, just not the data you're trying to scrape?

Comment: yes page load correctly and show on screen but when i want to scrap it data lost
with other simple sites all ok